# Is there a Python function equivalent to a Matlab bwmorph?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

I recently transferred Matlab code to Python, and I've tried OpenCV's `cv2.morphologyEx` and skimage's `skimage.morphology`, but the result is not the same as in Matlab. I can't find the equivalent function for the following Matlab code:

```
output = bwmorph(input, 'shrink', Inf)
```

For example, if the input array is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1;
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
 1, 0, 1, 0, 1;
 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Then the output array will be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In [Matlab's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html), I thought that the operation is similar to erosion, so I applied OpenCV to this array but got a different output:

```
output = cv2.erode(input, np.ones([3,3]))

output =
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Could anybody please point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Comment: Please, you need to be more specific with the expected result. Can you put here what type of result you expect?

Comment: Post examples: input plus results from each method.  Post a link to the explanation of the Matlab code or to the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Giba I've edited the post with an example.

Comment: @fmw42, sorry for the previous post. I've edited it, and I hope this statement makes the question more complete.

Comment: It is not clear what "shrink" does. Show us the result on the circles image in the documentation, since they do not show an example of each operation.

Comment: I do not think OpenCV has such an operation. One would need to know the algorithm used for "shrink" to see if it can be scripted.

Comment: When you have example images such as yours with a few scattered points, it will be hard to match or even come close without knowing how "shrink" is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "shrink" operation is called in different ways, including "thinning" and "ultimate thinning". Thinning is related to the skeleton, in that an approximation to the skeleton can be computed by thinning. But if you continue the thinning operation not keeping the end points (i.e. repeatedly removing the pixel at the end of branches) then eventually you'll end up with an image that has only isolated pixels and loops. This is what "shrink" does.

Scikit-image, in the `morphology` module, has `thin()`, `skeletonize()` and `medial_axis()`. They’re all similar, different approximations to the skeleton. There is no option to remove the end points.

OpenCV has `thinning()` in the `cv::ximgproc` module. It also cannot do your "shrink".

DIPlib has a function [`dip.EuclideanSkeleton`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-EuclideanSkeleton-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL) that does remove skeleton end points when choosing the option `"loose ends away"`.

The function has a downside in that it doesn't process a 2-pixel border around the image. So to get results all the way to the edges of the image, we need to add two pixels to each side of the image, which we then crop from the result.

DIPlib uses its own objects to store images, but they're compatible with NumPy. Inputs can be NumPy arrays, but the outputs will always be `dip.Image` objects. We can easily convert them back to a NumPy array. Note that this particular function requires a binary image as input, so we cast the NumPy array to Boolean first.

```py
import numpy as np
import diplib as dip

input = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
h, w = input.shape

tmp = input.astype(np.bool_)
tmp = dip.ExtendImage(tmp, 2, ["add zeros"])
output = dip.EuclideanSkeleton(tmp, endPixelCondition="loose ends away")
output.Crop((w, h))

output = np.asarray(output, dtype=np.int_)
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

---

Disclosure: I'm an author of DIPlib, but did not implement `dip.EuclideanSkeleton()`.

Comment: Not quite true about OpenCV and thinning. See cv::ximgproc::thinning at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html#ga37002c6ca80c978edb6ead5d6b39740. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @fmw42 You are right. I so often see the same bad skeletonization code come by for OpenCV, which doesn't do skeletonization at all. I had assumed the functionality was not available otherwise. -- It seems you need to install the `opencv-contrib-python` package in Python to get that namespace. It's separate from the main library.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your assistance. Although the result is quite different in my real data, I think these differences between DIPlib and Matlab are acceptable.

Comment: @Y.Y.Chen They are different algorithms attempting to obtain the same concept, so it is unlikely for the two to produce the exact same results. Every algorithm is going to make a different choice. You can also try `dip.ConditionalThinning2D(tmp, endPixelCondition="lose")` ([docs](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-ConditionalThinning2D-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint--dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL)). But it’s probably going to be even more different, it’s really not as good at finding the middle of the objects.